# ngClass not applying classes on true expression?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have just started working with Angular 2 and typescript, facing some minor issues. 
I am using ngClass to apply dynamic classes on the value being true or false. But somehow it's not applying the class on condition getting valued to true.

```
<td *ngFor="let data of tableData.timesheetInputs.timesheetDays | dayfilterpipe:'DAY' ">
                <input [(ngModel)] ="data.amount" #day="ngModel" (keypress)="_keyPress($event)" (ngModelChange)="timesheetHourChanged(data.amount,'DAY',data.day)" [disabled]="inputViewState && !isEditable" [ngClass]="{'is-invalidTimeEntry': (data.amount === '') || ((data.amount)%(0.25) != 0)  || (data.amount > 24),'changed-hour': hourChanged}" />

            </td>
```

I am evaluating "hourChanged" flag in corresponding component class and values are coming properly. But it's not working on view part.

```
[ngClass]="{'is-invalidTimeEntry': (data.amount === '') || ((data.amount)%(0.25) != 0)  || (data.amount > 24),'changed-hour': hourChanged}"
```

Am I writing this expression correctly or some issue with that.

Edit: adding component code

```
@Component({
selector: 'timesheet-table',
templateUrl: './temp.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./temp.component.css','../../../node_modules/angular2-    busy/build/style/busy.css']
})

export class TempComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {
@Input()
tableData: Timesheet ; 
@Input()
inputViewState:boolean;
@Input()
isEditable:boolean;
@Output() onHourChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
private hourChanged:boolean;

constructor(private router: Router,
          private route: ActivatedRoute,
          private translate: TranslateService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.tableDataCopy = this.deepCopy(this.tableData);   
}

public hourEntryChanged(day:any,type:string):boolean{
let tLen = this.tableData.timesheetInputs.timesheetDays.length;
let tCopyLen = this.tableDataCopy.timesheetInputs.timesheetDays.length;

let tDays = this.tableData.timesheetInputs.timesheetDays;
let tCopyDays = this.tableDataCopy.timesheetInputs.timesheetDays;
for(let ind=0; ind<tLen ; ind++){
    if(tDays[ind].day === day && tDays[ind].type === type && tCopyDays[ind].day === day && tCopyDays[ind].type === type){
        if(tDays[ind].amount !== tCopyDays[ind].amount){
            this.onHourChange.emit(true);
            this.hourChanged = true;
        }
    }else{
       this.onHourChange.emit(false);
       this.hourChanged = false;
    }

}
  console.log(this.hourChanged);
return this.hourChanged;
}



}
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace the expression with `true` and check the result. Have you tried `console.log(expression)` in code to see what the actual result is?

Comment: Yes. with true it's applying the class. Also, I have debugged the code and everything is fine, value is coming properly.

Comment: Hard to believe. Sorry, no idea.

Comment: Try and pass data to a method and check what your expression evaluates to.

Comment: can we access any variable defined in Component class here in html directly. 
In my case hourChanged is coming undefined.

Comment: hourChanged variable is defined in Component Class and whenever any invalid changes are there I want to apply a class on basis of value of hourChanged.

Comment: What does `hourChanged` look like? Can you show the code of controller  (TypeScript)?

Comment: @KonradGarus added component code.

Comment: Is it possible that `hourEntryChanged` is called in a way that loses `this`? If you print `hourChanged` in the template, does it still say undefined? I mean putting plain `{{hourChanged}}` somewhere.

Is `hourEntryChanged` called at all?

Comment: Yes, but it's adding that class to all input boxes. What I want is , when user changes value in any input , it'll check with it's previous value and if it differs then it'll apply that 'changed-hour' class to that particular input only.